# Is it possible to Broadcast Spark Context?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm working in a scenario where i want to broadcast Spark context and get it in the other side. Is it possible in any other way? If not can someone explain why.

Any help is highly appreciated.

`final JavaStreamingContext jsc = new JavaStreamingContext(conf,
                    Durations.milliseconds(2000));
final JavaSparkContext context =    jsc.sc();
final Broadcast<JavaSparkContext> broadcastedFieldNames = context.broadcast(context);`

Here's what i'm trying to achieve. 
1. We have a XML EVENT that is coming form Kafka.
2. In the xml event we have one HDFS file path (hdfs:localhost//test1.txt) 
3. We are using SparkStreamContext to create a DSTREAM and fetch the xml. Using Map Function we are reading the file path in each xml. 
4. Now we need to read the file from HDFS (hdfs:localhost//test1.txt). 
To Read this i need sc.readfile so i'm trying to broadcast the spark context to executor for parallel read of the input file.
Currently we are using HDFS Read file but that will not read parallel right?

Comment: This is something that is not possible. You cannot initiate driver actions on the executor side. Probably there is fundamentally something wrong with your algorithm. Please explain what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You can delete row from apache spark but if you use spark as olap engine to run SQL queries you also conce check apache incubator carbondata its provide you support of update delete records and it build on top of spark

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the reply.  Here's what i'm trying to achieve.
1. We have a XML EVENT that is coming form Kafka
2. In the xml event we have one HDFS file path (hdfs:localhost//test1.txt) 
3. We are using SparkStreamContext to create a DSTREAM and fetch the xml. Using Map Function we are reading the file path in each xml.
4. Now we need to read the file from HDFS (hdfs:localhost//test1.txt). To Read this i need sc.readfile so im trying to broadcast the spark context to executor for parallel read of the input file
Currently we are using HDFS Read file but that wont read parallely right?

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete row using apache spark but if you use spark as olap engine to run SQL queries you also conce check apache incubator carbondata its provide you support of update delete records and it build on top of spark